# how do i iterate an ArrayList by 1 depending on what statement is true in a while loop

Tags: java

i want to iterate an array list by 1 each time a condition is true within the loop

ideal output:

forward[1]

stop[1]

forward[2]

stop[2]

forward[3]

etc....

The code above will only change from forward to stop if the condition is no longer true and whilst the condition IS TRUE it will only print once.

my current output:

forward [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

stop [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

now this program is intended to store directions and movements for a robot

i have tried the THREAD.SLEEP() method as well but this stops the robot from changing direction again until the sleep has ended.

any help would be appreciated

code:

```
ArrayList <Integer> forward = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList <Integer> stop = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private void follow()

while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {


        if (steve.Obstacle(true)){ // if a obstacle is found.

            stop.add(1);

        }
        else if(steve.stop(true)) {
            forward.add(1);
        }
  System.out.println("forward "+forward);
  System.out.println("stop "+stop);
}
```

Comment: Just store the `currentIndex` and increment that by one when the condition in your loop matches, then use the `List#get(int index)` method?

Comment: could you give a basic code example of how this would work?

Comment: You may want to use a Timer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Feel free to drop me a note when you got another question to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part one: printing arrays in the way you are looking for could be done like this:

```
int length = forward.size();
for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
  System.out.println("forward[" +i + "]: " + forward.get(i)));
  System.out.println("stop[" +i + "]: " + stop.get(i)));
```

Side note: of course that only works when both lists have **exactly** the same length. (and pre-computing the length prior to the loop saves a tiny bit of runtime overhead)

But: that won't work for you; since your code is simply **not** doing anything useful. I think you need some changes, something like:

```
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
    if (steve.Obstacle(true)){ // if a obstacle is found.
        stop.add(1);
    }
    else if(steve.stop(true)) {
        forward.add(1);
    }
    Thread.sleep(whatever);
}
```

The point is: if you do not use a sleep in here, then your loop runs at full CPU speed and just keeps adding values to those lists; so you probably end up with lists that many **millions** of ONE entries!

But: even when we slow down; you cant relate those list entries; as you only put 11111111 into both lists. Tells you ... nothing. So, why not do this:

```
List<String> movements = new ArrayList<>();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
    if (steve.Obstacle(true)){ // if a obstacle is found.
        movements.add("stopped");
    }
    else if(steve.stop(true)) {
        movements.add("forward");
    }
    Thread.sleep(whatever);
}
```

When you print that, you get something like

```
 stopped stopped stopped forward forward stopped ...
```

or so. And given your lastest comment: of **course** the whole thing only makes sense when there is **more** then one thread! You are saying that the sleeps stop your robot - then something is wrong. You see - in this loop, is there **any** code that would **change** what the robot is doing? My assumption was: your robot is doing its thing; and you want to use this loop to read its status while it is doing that.

Comment: i tried this and got this output    forward[0]: 1
stop[0]: 1
forward[1]: 1
stop[1]: 1
forward[2]: 1
stop[2]: 1
forward[3]: 1
stop[3]: 1
forward[4]: 1
stop[4]: 1
forward[5]: 1
stop[5]: 1
forward[6]: 1
stop[6]: 1
forward[7]: 1
stop[7]: 1

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say with that comment? Isnt that what you were looking for?

Comment: i am trying to get the program to print out a sequence of movements, so what i would like ideally is a program that prints out each direction i am moving only once so..   (forward1) would be the only printed output if this for example was the only direction i was moving for the whole duration of the loop

Comment: so for the string array it would work the same way as the int array, the thread.sleep(whatever) stops my robot from changing direction until the thread has ended, which stops robot from moving efficiently, so without the thread.sleep(whatever) i get this output  :  [forward, forward, forward, forward, forward, forward, forward, forward]

Answer (score 0):

It's just adding one every time. You have to increment it every time and add that.

```
private void follow()
int stopInt = 0;
int forwardInt = 0;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        if (steve.Obstacle(true)){
            stop.add(stopInt);
            stopInt++;
        }
        else if(steve.stop(true)) {
            forward.add(forwardInt);
            forwardInt++;
        }
  System.out.println("forward "+forward);
  System.out.println("stop "+stop);
```

Comment: Your code is not even compiling; you cant call ++ on like `stop++;` stop is a LIST!

Comment: fixed. meant to ++ the ints

Comment: Makes some sense now ;-)